# Angular CLI generated app with Web Workers

Tags: angular, web-worker

Reading the Angular Documentation, you can find several [references to bootstrap your whole Angular app inside a Web Worker](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/PlatformLocation-class.html), so your UI won't get blocked by heavy JS usage.

However, at this moment there's no official information on how to do that, and the only info in the Angular Doc. is that this is an experimental feature.

How can I use this approach to take advantage of web workers in Angular?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**For Angular 7, see answer below.**

I spent a lot of time to figure out how to do it, so I hope [this can help someone](https://medium.com/@enriqueoriol/angular-with-web-workers-step-by-step-dc11d5872135).

## Preconditions

I’m assuming that you have an Angular project (version 2 or 4) generated with Angular CLI 1.0 or higher.

It is not mandatory to generate the project with CLI to follow this steps, but the instructions I'll give related with the webpack file, are be based on the CLI webpack config.

## Steps

### 1. Extract webpack file

Since Angular CLI v1.0, there’s the “eject” feature, that allows you to extract the webpack config file and manipulate it as you wish.

- Run `ng eject` so Angular CLI generates the **webpack.config.js** file.
- Run `npm install` so the new dependencies generated by CLI are satisfied

### 2. Install webworker bootstrap dependencies

Run `npm install --save @angular/platform-webworker @angular/platform-webworker-dynamic`

### 3. Changes in UI thread bootstrap

#### 3.1 Changes in app.module.ts

Replace `BrowserModule` by `WorkerAppModule` in the app.module.ts file. You’ll also need to update the import statement in order to use `@angular/platform-webworker` library.

```js
//src/app/app.module.ts

import { WorkerAppModule } from '@angular/platform-webworker';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
//...other imports...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    WorkerAppModule,
    //...other modules...
  ],
  providers: [/*...providers...*/],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

#### 3.2 Changes in src/main.ts

Replace bootstrap process with: `bootstrapWorkerUI` (update also the import).

You’ll need to pass a URL with the file where the web worker is defined. Use a file called `webworker.bundle.js`, don’t worry, we will create this file soon.

```js
//main.ts

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapWorkerUi } from '@angular/platform-webworker';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrapWorkerUi('webworker.bundle.js');
```

#### 3.3 Create workerLoader.ts file

- Create a **new file src/workerLoader.ts**.
- As your Web Worker will be a single file containing all the required stuff, you need to include `polyfills.ts`, `@angular/core`, and `@angular/common` packages. On next steps, you will update Webpack in order to transpile and build a bundle with the result.
- Import `platformWorkerAppDynamic`
- Import the `AppModule` (remove the import from **main.ts**) and bootstrap it using this `platformWorkerAppDynamic` platform.

```js
// workerLoader.ts

import 'polyfills.ts';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/common';

import { platformWorkerAppDynamic } from '@angular/platform-webworker-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformWorkerAppDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

### 4. Update webpack to build your webworker

The webpack auto generated config file is quite long, but you’ll just need to center your attention in the following things:

- Add a `webworker`**entry point** for our `workerLoader.ts` file. If you look at the output, you’ll see that it attaches a bundle.js prefix to all chunks. That’s why during bootstrap step we have used `webworker.bundle.js`
- Go to **HtmlWebpackPlugin** and exclude the `webworker` entry point, so the generated Web Worker file is not included in the index.html file.
- Go to **CommonChunksPlugin**, and for the `inline` common chunk, set the entry chunks explicitely to prevent `webworker` to be included.
- Go to **AotPlugin** and set explicitely the `entryModule`

```js
// webpack.config.js

//...some stuff...
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CommonsChunkPlugin } = require('webpack').optimize;
const { AotPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack');
//...some stuff...

module.exports = {
  //...some stuff...
  "entry": {
    "main": [
      "./src/main.ts"
    ],
    "polyfills": [
      "./src/polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "styles": [
      "./src/styles.css"
    ],
    "webworker": [
      "./src/workerLoader.ts"
    ]
  },
  "output": {
    "path": path.join(process.cwd(), "dist"),
    "filename": "[name].bundle.js",
    "chunkFilename": "[id].chunk.js"
  },
  "module": { /*...a lot of stuff...*/ },
  "plugins": [
    //...some stuff...
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      //...some stuff...
      "excludeChunks": [
        "webworker"
      ],
      //...some more stuff...
    }),
    new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({}),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
      "name": "inline",
      "minChunks": null,
      "chunks": [
        "main",
        "polyfills",
        "styles"
      ]
    }),
    //...some stuff...
    new AotPlugin({
      "mainPath": "main.ts",
      "entryModule": "app/app.module#AppModule",
      //...some stuff...
    })
  ],
  //...some more stuff...
};
```

## You’re ready

If you have followed correctly the previous steps, now you only need to compile the code and try the results.

Run `npm start`

All the logic of your Angular app should be running inside a WebWorker, causing the UI to be more fluent.

## Furter notes

`npm start` runs the **webpack-dev server**, and it has some kind of problem with webworkers throwing an error message on console log. Anyway, the webworker seems to run fine.
If you compile the app using `webpack` command and serve it from any http server like [simplehttpserver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simplehttpserver), the error goes away ;)

## Sample code and demo

You can get the whole code (webpack config, app.module.ts, ...) from [this repo](https://github.com/kaikcreator/angular-cli-web-worker).

You can also watch here a [live demo](https://kaikcreator.github.io/angular-cli-web-worker/), to check out differences between using Web Workers or not

Comment: Great answer @Kaik !! Thanks for helping the community about all that :) Out of curiosity, have you notice a perf improvement ?

Comment: @Maxime you can try the demo in the link. There's a huge benefit in terms of user experience, as UI works smoothly even if you are running heavy stuff inside the business logic.

Comment: I didn't saw the demo link earlier thanks for pointing that out ! It's incredible ... Can't wait to try that on my app ! Thanks again :)

Comment: @KaiK great answer! I just tried running this on a fresh install of cli v1.0 and when i run npm start the page just hangs on Loading...

Comment: @JackClancy is the console showing you any  error? You can download the code from the repo and check if there's some difference with your project

Comment: Great job, did you get a change to run Angular Material 2 with Web Worker and complete Ionic 2 App in Web Worker?

Comment: Good answer, but, for more complex projects there's a whole host of issues with postcss, module loading and associated webpack nasties to sort out. Including the fact that webworker.js seems to load twice if you need to hash your output files. I've not sorted them all out yet, but I'll post a round-up if I do.

Comment: @Ced It really is very tricky. I was getting a whole host of errors (mostly postcss stuff) and it is a huge time drain. I have hived the project off from my main code base and return when time permits.I still haven't found the reason that webworker.js is loading twice. One is in includes and the other is via generated code. I'm going to have another go this weekend.

Comment: @EnriqueOriol - thanks for the detailed answer. I am using web-animations and getting the error `web-animations.min.js:15 Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined` when trying to load the page. Do you think you can help me out there ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @belafarinrod91 probably web-animations is using unsafe DOM APIs, like "document", and because you cannot access the DOM in webworkers, you're getting this error

Comment: @EnriqueOriol so there is no solution yet ?

Comment: @belafarinrod91 Angular provides safe DOM API for accessing and altering the DOM in order to be able to do that stuff and run the code in multiple platforms (like Webworkers). The problem here is not Angular, but the library "web-animations" you're trying to include. That is what causes the error, the same way your app will throw an error if you try to provide through server side rendering, because "document" is neither present in NodeJS. You should remove that library and do whatever animations you want to do using CSS or Angular.

Comment: @EnriqueOriol thanks for your explanations, but I need to use the `web-animations` polyfill to ensure that the angular animations are executed in IE and FF ... so probably there is currently no solution available to fulfill my requirements. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am using `material2` and after using this solution I get an error `hammer.js:2643 Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined`. It seems that Angular should get rid of all 3rd party libraries that does not use the safe DOM API

Comment: @MurhafSousli If you are using material2 it is not possible to use webworker as it makes many calls to manipulate the DOM. Currently material2 and webworkers are a non-starter.

Comment: I had follow the same steps but got following errors ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed: F:\~\angular-cli-master\angular-cli-master\packages\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.ts:2
import { satisfies } from 'semver';ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
Module build failed: F:\~\angular-cli-master\angular-cli-master\packages\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.ts:2
import { satisfies } from 'semver';

Comment: @EnriqueOriol: thx for your nice guide above - do you know why `(dragstart)` doesn't work in templates? I included this approach https://www.radzen.com/blog/angular-drag-and-drop/, but it doesn't work. I thought it's connected to the `@HostListener` but even `(dragstart)` didn't work. `(click)` event worked right away. `onDragstart="..."`worked as well.

Comment: No idea why `(dragstart)` is not working and `onDragstart` works fine. Don't know if it is related, but remember Web workers do not have access to DOM.

Comment: @Enrique, I am getting error when running 'npm start' -  module.js:557
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@ngtools/webpack'. How to fix esissue, Can you suggest something?

Comment: @Ahmadmnzr as you can see in the "Further notes" section, 
`npm start` runs the webpack-dev server, and it has some kind of problem with webworkers throwing an error message on console log, but the webworker seems to run fine.If you compile the app using webpack command and serve it from any http server like simplehttpserver, the error goes away ;)

Comment: Thanks,ok, but how to compile the app using webpack command and serve it.

Comment: I get `Error: webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin has been removed, please use config.optimization.splitChunks instead.`

Comment: Thanks for this article. `ng eject` has been disabled in `Angular 7.0.1`.. how to move further?

Comment: This post needs to be updated to angular 7. By the way, animations doesn't work with platform webworker

Comment: A bit late to the party but I'd like to see how I can do that with Angular 12, especially since `eject` is no longer an option, plus they switched to Webpack 5...

Answer (score 2):

Good news guys, I got this to work with Angular 7!

**Requirement**: `npm install --save-dev @angular-builders/custom-webpack html-webpack-plugin`
**Make sure that you have `production:true`** in your env file if you just want to copy/past code from below.

**Step 1**: Edit your angular.json file the following way:

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
                "path": "./webpack.client.config.js",
                "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
             },
            ...
          }
```

You are only editing the `build` part because you don't really need the whole worker thing in dev server.

**Step 2**: Create `webpack.client.config.js` file at the root of your project. **If you're not using SSR, you can remove `exclude: ['./server.ts'],`**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { AngularCompilerPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    webworker: [
      "./src/workerLoader.ts"
    ],
    main: [
      "./src/main.ts"
    ],
    polyfills: [
      "./src/polyfills.ts"
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      excludeChunks: [
        "webworker"
      ],
      chunksSortMode: "none"
    }),
    new AngularCompilerPlugin({
      mainPath: "./src/main.ts",
      entryModule: './src/app/app.module#AppModule',
      tsConfigPath: "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      exclude: ['./server.ts'],
      sourceMap: true,
      platform: 0
    }),
  ],
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      name: "inline"
    }
  }
}
```

**Step 3**: Edit you AppModule:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { WorkerAppModule } from '@angular/platform-webworker'
```

```
const AppBootstrap =
            environment.production
            ? WorkerAppModule
            : BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'myApp' })
```

```
    imports: [
        ...
        AppBootstrap,
        ...
    ]
```

**Step 4**: Edit you main.ts file.

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { bootstrapWorkerUi } from '@angular/platform-webworker';

import {AppModule} from './app/app.module';
import {environment} from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
  bootstrapWorkerUi('webworker.bundle.js');
}

else {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
  });
}
```

**Step 5**: It will compile just fine, but you may have a runtime issue due to DOM manipulation in your app. At this point you just have to remove any DOM manipulation and replace it by something else. I'm still working at figuring this part out and will edit my answer later to give direction about this issue.

If you're not doing savage DOM manipulation, then you're good to go with a free main-thread and auditing your app using lighthouse should not show `Minimize main-thread work` anymore, as most of your app except UI loads in a second thread.

Comment: The issue is like: Cannot find window in a line like window[&#39;webpackJSONPCallback&#39;]??? You got nothing. You have to use webpack multiple targets to compile it, but angular cli don&#39;t support an array in the webpack config. Lazy loading won&#39;t work for this reason.

Comment: Really ? I don't have this issue on my end even though I use lazy loading.

Comment: So how do you load lazy modules with webpack configured with target: 'web'? You have to get an error: cannot find window. Isn't it? If not, show me an example. I'm absolutely sure this won't work. See this: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/