# Run Angular app inside web worker without ejecting from CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli, web-worker

I have some heavy javascript code in my application and it is bogging down the UI, making it feel less than 60fps (janky).

I want to take advantage of using a web worker without losing the comfort of the angular-cli (I don't want to run `ng eject`). Ideally, my whole app would run inside the web worker.

Is this currently possible?

**Preconditions:**

- Angular 2 or 4
- Angular-cli v.1.0+
- No ejecting from angular-cli

Comment: you try running this heavy javascript code outside of Angular zone so that Angular doesn't trigger change detection

Comment: That's a good idea. I I'll try that out :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you saw this: [Angular CLI generated app with Web Workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276044/angular-cli-generated-app-with-web-workers/43276045)

And this: https://medium.com/@enriqueoriol/angular-with-web-workers-step-by-step-dc11d5872135

But didn't like the ejecting?

I don't know of any way to do that currently. There is an issue to add it here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2305

So the disappointing answer to your question may be "no".