# How to configure Angular-CLI-generated project to include a SharedWorker

Tags: angular, angular-cli, web-worker, shared-worker, lovefield

What are the specific steps to add a `SharedWorker` to an `@angular/cli >1.2`-generated project. I would like the SharedWorker to be defined in TypeScript (with full/correct type-definitions editor support), to share interfaces with the main project, and to be continuously compiled and tested along with the main project.

I haven't discovered an example or blog post that describes how to modify a cli-generated project to include either a `Worker` or a `SharedWorker`. However, there are several posts (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43276045/852956) one) which show how to transform an entire cli-generated project to run it as a web worker. But that's not my use-case.

I want to confine interaction with a [Lovefield](https://github.com/google/lovefield) database to a `SharedWorker` that runs in a separate process from the main application.

Though I've experimented a bit attempting to figure this out, I haven't made much progress. Hopefully someone can save me (and future readers) a lot of time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got this to work following these steps:

1. Create folder `src\app\shared-worker`
2. Create file  `src\app\shared-worker\shared-worker.d.ts` with the following contents:

   **SharedWorker definitions**

   ```
   declare module SharedWorker {
       interface AbstractWorker extends EventTarget {
           onerror: (ev: ErrorEvent) => any;
       }
       export interface SharedWorker extends AbstractWorker {
           port: MessagePort;
           onconnect: (messageEvent: MessageEvent) => void;
       }
   }
   declare var SharedWorker: {
       prototype: SharedWorker.SharedWorker;
       new(stringUrl: string, name?: string): SharedWorker.SharedWorker;
   };
   // Merely added the onconnect() method to the file provied via:
   // npm install --save-dev retyped-sharedworker-tsd-ambient
   // Definitions by: Toshiya Nakakura <https://github.com/nakakura>
   ```
3. Create file `src\app\shared-worker\shared-worker.ts` with the following demo contents:

   **Sharedworker source**

   ```
   /// <reference path=".\shared-worker.d.ts" />

   (<any>self).onconnect = (connectEvent: MessageEvent) => {
       const messagePort: MessagePort = (connectEvent.ports as MessagePort[])[0];

       messagePort.onmessage = function (messageEvent: MessageEvent) {
           const workerResult: number = messageEvent.data.firstNumber * messageEvent.data.secondNumber;
           messagePort.postMessage(workerResult);
       };

   };
   ```
4. Update `src\app\app.component.ts` as follows:

   **AppComponent**

   ```
   import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
   import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
   import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

   @Component({
       selector: 'app-root',
       template: `
   <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="firstNumber" />
   <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="secondNumber" />
   <hr /><button (click)="postMessageToSharedWorker()">Invoke Shared Worker</button>
   <hr /><div>Result: {{result$ | async}}</div>`
   })
   export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
       public firstNumber = 4;
       public secondNumber = 8;
       private resultSubject = new Subject<number>();
       private sharedWorker: SharedWorker.SharedWorker;
       public result$: Observable<number>;

       public ngOnInit(): void {
           this.result$ = this.resultSubject.asObservable();
           if ('SharedWorker' in window) {
               this.sharedWorker = new SharedWorker('app/shared-worker/shared-worker.js');
               this.sharedWorker.port.onmessage = (messageEvent: MessageEvent) => {
                   this.resultSubject.next(messageEvent.data);
                   this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
               };
           }
       }

       public postMessageToSharedWorker() {
           if (!('SharedWorker' in window)) {
               return;
           }
           this.sharedWorker.port.postMessage({ firstNumber: this.firstNumber, secondNumber: this.secondNumber });
       }
       constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
   }
   ```
5. Add `"app/shared-worker/shared-worker.js"` to the `apps.assets` node in `.angular-cli.json`
6. Install `concurrently` as a dev dependency: `npm i -D concurrently`
7. Create `package.json` scripts

   **package.json**

   ```
   "wrk-w": "tsc --noLib --experimentalDecorators --watch node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts src/app/shared-worker/shared-worker.d.ts src/app/shared-worker/shared-worker.ts",
   "dev": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run wrk-w\" \"npm run start\""
   ```

Comment: I gave up on trying to get this content formatted properly. This editor is abysmal.

Comment: Helped a bit with the formatting.. there is a bug/feature with the editor, that you cannot have a code block while being inside a (numbered) list. So adding a title before the code works

Comment: @PierreDuc you can have code blocks within numbered lists. You just have to indent it a little more.

Comment: @Stefan well would you look at that, it's a miracle! :D

Answer (score 2):

Just install @types/sharedworker and add it to tsconfig.app.json in "types" array option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CLI to generate a standard dedicated [Web Worker](https://angular.io/guide/web-worker) and then update the code to use Shared Worker instead.

```
new SharedWorker(new URL('./shared.worker', import.meta.url))
```

Angular CLI will handle compilation and bundling the worker file automatically.