# Use router in angular2/4 running in webworker

Tags: angular, web-worker

I used these topics [Angular CLI generated app with Web Workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276044/angular-cli-generated-app-with-web-workers) and https://github.com/kaikcreator/angular-cli-web-worker to running my entire angular4 application in web worker.

My final question is "How use angular router with angular4 application entirely running in webworker".

My problem is when I use

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

in AppModule, I have this error :

```
zone.js:690 Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for PlatformLocation! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: No provider for PlatformLocation!
at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)
at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1207)
at ReflectiveInjector_../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2649)
at ReflectiveInjector_../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2688)
at ReflectiveInjector_../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (core.es5.js:2620)
at ReflectiveInjector_../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.get (core.es5.js:2489)
at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9492)
at _callFactory (core.es5.js:9558)
at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.es5.js:9506)
at initNgModule (core.es5.js:9456) Error: No provider for PlatformLocation!
at injectionError (http://localhost:4200/webworker.bundle.js:35604:90)
at noProviderError (http://localhost:4200/webworker.bundle.js:35642:12)
at ReflectiveInjector_../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:4200/webworker.bundle.js:37084:19)
at ReflectiveInjector_../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:4200/webworker.bundle.js:37123:25)
at ReflectiveInjector_../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:4200/webworker.bundle.js:37055:25)
at ReflectiveInjector_../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:4200/webworker.bundle.js:36924:21)
at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:4200/webworker.bundle.js:43927:25)
at _callFactory (http://localhost:4200/webworker.bundle.js:43993:28)
at _createProviderInstance$1 (http://localhost:4200/webworker.bundle.js:43941:26)
at initNgModule (http://localhost:4200/webworker.bundle.js:43891:28)
```

Official angular4 webworker documentation doesnt exist ....

Thx for help !

EDIT :

main.ts :

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapWorkerUi, WORKER_UI_LOCATION_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/platform-webworker';

import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrapWorkerUi('../webworker.bundle.js', WORKER_UI_LOCATION_PROVIDERS);
```

WORKER_UI_LOCATION_PROVIDERS is useless here. I saw (somewhere on the web) that is the good way.

app.module.ts

```
import { WorkerAppModule } from '@angular/platform-webworker';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    WorkerAppModule,
    CoreModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: environment.baseHref },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

my app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Routes = [
  // { path: '', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full'},
  // { path: '', loadChildren: './main-layout/main-layout.module#MainLayoutModule' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is due missing `NativeScriptRouterModule` inside imports the in main.ts file.

Could be also `platformBrowserDynamic`

Hope it helps (paste your main.ts and app.module.ts files to be more specific please)

Comment: Great thanks to reply. I'm not use "NativeScript". I understood "NativeScript" is "only" for dev angular app on mobile, no ? For do it, I use Cordova (without Ionic cause no time to migrate my project on it). I will edit my question to past files.

Answer (score 0):

here working example with routing in web worker. [Example](https://github.com/shanhaichik/angular-workers-in-action)
I try it with lazy, it works fine

Comment: Thx for your reply. I used other method for optimize my app (ChangeDetectorRef) with detach() and detectChanges(). I ll try your solution more later.