# Running Angular 5 app inside webworker causes window object to be undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular5

I am trying to upgrade [this (ngx-admin)](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin) free Angular template to Angular 5 and then trying to run the whole app inside WebWorker as mentioned in this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276044/angular-cli-generated-app-with-web-workers#answer-43276045).

I successfully upgraded the app to Angular 5 and it is working fine but when I try to configure the app to run inside Webworker it gives me following error:

[image]

[image]

The complete code (modified to Angular 5 and webworker) can be found [here](https://github.com/SaurabhLpRocks/ng2-webworker-demo)

I tried to add DefinePlugin in my webpack config but no luck.

**webpack.config.json:**

```
new DefinePlugin({
  window: undefined,
  document: undefined
}),
```

I was able to run new empty angular-cli application inside webworker but I am unable to run this template inside webworker. I guess there is some node package which is creating issue.

**Package.json:**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "conventional-changelog": "conventional-changelog",
    "e2e": "protractor ./protractor.conf.js",
    "docs": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs",
    "docs:serve": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs -s",
    "release:changelog": "npm run conventional-changelog -- -p angular -i CHANGELOG.md -s",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port=4200",
    "test": "karma start ./karma.conf.js",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false --quiet"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "5.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "5.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "5.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "5.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "5.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-webworker": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-webworker-dynamic": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "5.1.2",
    "@asymmetrik/angular2-leaflet": "^2.2.1",
    "@nebular/auth": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@nebular/theme": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^7.0.1",
    "angular2-chartjs": "0.3.0",
    "angular2-leaflet": "^0.1.0",
    "angular2-toaster": "4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
    "chart.js": "2.5.0",
    "ckeditor": "4.6.2",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "d3": "4.8.0",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "ionicons": "2.0.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.2.0",
    "nebular-icons": "1.0.6",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "1.1.9",
    "ng2-smart-table": "1.1.0",
    "ng2-tree": "2.0.0-alpha.10",
    "ngx-charts": "^3.0.2",
    "ngx-echarts": "1.2.2",
    "normalize.css": "6.0.0",
    "pace-js": "1.0.2",
    "roboto-fontface": "0.8.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "socicon": "3.0.5",
    "tether": "1.4.0",
    "tinymce": "4.5.7",
    "typeface-exo": "0.0.22",
    "web-animations-js": "2.2.5",
    "zone.js": "0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "5.1.2",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "1.0.5",
    "@types/d3-color": "1.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.54",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.2.4",
    "@types/node": "8.5.2",
    "codelyzer": "3.2.1",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "1.3.4",
    "husky": "0.13.3",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.1",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "stylelint": "7.13.0",
    "ts-node": "3.2.2",
    "tslint": "5.7.0",
    "tslint-language-service": "0.9.6",
    "typescript": "2.6.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~2.9.3",
    "webpack": "~3.8.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.1",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "postcss-url": "^5.1.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack-concat-plugin": "1.4.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.1.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it work with "npm run build --prod --no--aot" ?

Comment: I cloned your repo and tried to compile the app and getting various errors.  One of which is the version of `webpack-concat-plugin` is very out of date and throws an error and your version `2.6.2` of typescript is [not yet supported with Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).  Are you sure your installed dependencies match what's in your package.json file?

Comment: Saurabh: Did you follow the instructions in the "further notes" section at the end of the post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Web workers does not run in a window and does therefore not have the window object.
However, if you are using libraries that use the window object, you can assign it yourself using the self variable at the top of your code.

```
const window = self;
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers):

> A worker is an object created using a constructor (e.g. Worker()) that
>   runs a named JavaScript file — this file contains the code that will
>   run in the worker thread; workers run in another global context that
>   is different from the current window. Thus, **using the window shortcut
>   to get the current global scope (instead of self) within a Worker will
>   return an error.**
>
> The worker context is represented by a **DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope**
>   object in the case of dedicated workers (standard workers that are
>   utilized by a single script; shared workers use
>   SharedWorkerGlobalScope). A dedicated worker is only accessible from
>   the script that first spawned it, whereas shared workers can be
>   accessed from multiple scripts.

Comment: @Jomare is right. Webworkers are supposed to be a support for background process for the window. Not the other way round. Run a process or a function and web workers should run fine. DOM access fundamentals dont change.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this to the webpack config file:

```
output: {
...
globalObject: "this"
}
```

**Edit:**
The previous solution is a little bit tricky. If you really make a webworker bundle, you'll have to use webpack multiple targets. (Webpack version >= 4.12.0)

```
export.module= [
         {
           target: 'web',
           // Webpack config here for bundle that will work in UI thread.
         },
         {
           target: 'webworker',
           // Webpack config here for bundle that will work in the worker.
         }
]
```