# Structuring a TypeScript project with workers

Tags: typescript, service-worker, web-worker

How should I structure a project that includes main thread (DOM) script, and workers? Eg:

## main.ts

```
// This file must have DOM types, but not worker types.

const worker = new Worker('worker.js');

worker.onmessage = (event) => {
  // Ideally, I should be able to reference types from the worker:
  const data = event.data as import('./worker').HelloMessage;
  console.log(data.hello);
};
```

## worker.ts

```
// This file must have worker types, but not DOM types.
// The global object must be one of the worker globals (how do I pick which?)

const helloMessage = {
  hello: 'world',
};

export type HelloMessage = typeof helloMessage;

postMessage(helloMessage);
```

Whenever I've tried this in the past I feel like I've been fighting TypeScript by either:

- Using one `tsconfig.json` that has both worker & DOM types. But of course this isn't accurate type-wise.
- Using multiple `tsconfig.json`. But then the project boundary makes it hard to reference types between them.

Additionally, how do I declare the global in a worker? Previously I've used `declare var self: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope`, but is there a way to actually set the global (rather than just setting `self`)?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Many thanks to [Mattias Buelens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1321716/mattias-buelens) who pointed me in the right direction.

[Here's a working example](https://github.com/jakearchibald/typescript-worker-example).

The project structure is:

- `dist`
- `src`

  - `generic-tsconfig.json`
  - `main`

    - (typescript files)
    - `tsconfig.json`
  - `dedicated-worker`

    - (typescript files)
    - `tsconfig.json`
  - `service-worker`

    - (typescript files)
    - `tsconfig.json`

## `src/generic-tsconfig.json`

This contains the config common to each project:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "../dist",
    "composite": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

I've deliberately avoided calling this `tsconfig.json`, as it isn't a project itself. Adapt the above to your needs. Here are the important parts:

- `outDir` - This is where the transpiled script, declarations and source maps will go.
- `rootDir` - By setting this to the `src` directory, each of the subprojects (`main`, `dedicated-worker`, `service-worker`) will appear as subdirectories in the `outDir`, otherwise they'll try and share the same directory and overwrite each other.
- `composite` - This is required for TypeScript to keep references between projects.

Do not include `references` in this file. They'll be ignored for some undocumented reason (this is where I got stuck).

## `src/main/tsconfig.json`

This is the config for the 'main thread' project, As in, the JavaScript that will have access to the document.

```
{
  "extends": "../generic-tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
  },
  "references": [
    {"path": "../dedicated-worker"},
    {"path": "../service-worker"}
  ]
}
```

- `extends` - This points to our generic config above.
- `compilerOptions.lib` - The libs used by this project. In this case, JS and the DOM.
- `references` - Since this is the main project (the one we build), it must reference all other subprojects to ensure they're also built.

## `src/dedicated-worker/tsconfig.json`

This is the config for the dedicated worker (the kind you create with `new Worker()`).

```
{
  "extends": "../generic-tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["esnext", "webworker"],
  }
}
```

You don't need to reference the other sub projects here unless you import things from them (eg types).

## Using dedicated worker types

TypeScript doesn't differentiate between different worker contexts, despite them having different globals. As such, things get a little messy:

```
postMessage('foo');
```

This works, as TypeScript's "webworker" types create globals for all dedicated worker globals. However:

```
self.postMessage('foo');
```

…this fails, as TypeScript gives `self` a non-existent type that's sort-of an abstract worker global.

To fix this, include this in your source:

```
declare var self: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope;
export {};
```

This sets `self` to the correct type.

The `declare var` bit doesn't work unless the file is a module, and the dummy export makes TypeScript treat it as a module. This means you're declaring `self` in the module scope, which doesn't currently exist. Otherwise, you're trying to declare it on the global, where it *does* already exist.

## `src/service-worker/tsconfig.json`

Same as above.

```
{
  "extends": "../generic-tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["esnext", "webworker"],
  }
}
```

## Using service worker types

As above, TypeScript's "webworker" types create globals for all dedicated worker globals. But this isn't a dedicated worker, so some of the types are incorrect:

```
postMessage('yo');
```

TypeScript doesn't complain about the above, but it'll fail at runtime as `postMessage` isn't on the service worker global.

Unfortunately there's nothing you can do to fix the real global, but you can still fix `self`:

```
declare var self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;
export {};
```

Now you need to ensure every global that's special to service workers is accessed via `self`.

```
addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  // This is a type error, as the global addEventListener
  // doesn't know anything about the 'fetch' event.
  // Therefore it doesn't know about event.request.
  console.log(event.request);
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  // This works fine.
  console.log(event.request);
});
```

The same issues and workarounds exist for other worker types, such as worklets and shared workers.

## Building

```sh
tsc --build src/main
```

And that's it!

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation, @JaffaTheCake ! Bookmarking this.

Comment: Great answer +1. FYI I have created a minimal setup with a working example for TS with Web Worker, here my solution: https://github.com/gibbok/typescript-web-workers I use a cast to DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope to help TS get the types for self. I hope could be useful.

Comment: @GibboK that project you linked doesn't solve the issue of conflicts between worker and dom types because it omits dom types completely, I think your example might be too minimal to be helpful in a real world situation.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using a standard setup with Vite + TS and I did not want to fiddle around with multiple tsconfigs, as the only thing I needed was a reference to the `webworkers` lib (and the rest to be the same).

This can be achieved by using a [tripleslash directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) in the worker.js:

```
/// <reference lib="webworker" />

// ...
// rest of the worker code
// ...
postMessage("hi", [transferable]);
```

As @Majaha mentions, keep in mind that this may include the lib to the whole project.

Comment: This doesn't work because it globally includes the webworker library, conflicting with the dom library. It doesn't scope the webworker types to just this file like you might hope.

Comment: That's a good point. In the case of my project, this suffices for now.