# How can i use axios in js file in vuejs cli project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, axios, web-worker

I need use axios inside a webworker defined in js file.

This is a Hello World CLI project in vue3, with only axios installed (npm install axios)

[image]

[image]

The output:
[image]

This work fine, but when i uncomment **import axios from "axios"** in webworker.js I get the following error in the console:

> webworker.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

How can i use axios inside a webworker?

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931878/how-to-import-a-library-like-moment-js-into-a-web-worker

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a library like moment.js into a web worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931878/how-to-import-a-library-like-moment-js-into-a-web-worker)

Comment: Michael Mano, I did not find solutions in that link. I looked everywhere and I can't find the answer