# How to import modules with web workers?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, webpack, parallel-processing, web-worker

How do I import a library like `jimp` or `moment` in a Web worker?

I tried to follow the answers given here [How to import a library like moment.js into a web worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931878/how-to-import-a-library-like-moment-js-into-a-web-worker), but they did not work:

With the entry point, the bundle file was never produced and I couldn't use the web worker.

With the `web-worker`, it says Attempted import error:

`'./myWorker.worker.js' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Worker').`

I also tried the solution given here:

[Web Workers - How To Import Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118600/web-workers-how-to-import-modules)

I was able to access the WebWorker and get it to post a message (unlike in the above solutions), but as soon as I add `import` statements, it just gives an error like this:

[image]

How can I fix this?