# Using web worker in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, web-worker

I have angular app created with `Angular CLI`. I want to use `Web Worker` for creating `thread`.
My idea is to do heavy calculation in background `thread` and post back response to the main `thread` once completed.

I have `worker.js`

```
self.addEventListener('message', (evt) => {
  switch (evt.data.cmd) {
    case 'CALCULATE':{
      let payload = evt.data.payload;
      let response = calculateFunction(payload);    
      let response = {
        cmd: 'RESPONSE',
        payload: response 
      }
      postMessage(response);
      break;
    }
    default:
      throw Error(`Invalid command: ${evt.data.cmd}`);
    }
});
```

In Component :

```
private worker: Worker;
constructor() {
    this.initWebWorker();
}

initWebWorker(){
 let url = '/dist/assets/workers/worker.js';
 this.worker = new Worker(url);
 this.worker.addEventListener('message', (evt)=>{
  switch (evt.data.cmd) {
    case 'RESPONSE':{
      let payload = evt.data.payload;
      console.log(payload)
      break;
    }
    default:
      throw Error(`Invalid command: ${evt.data.cmd}`);
   }
  });
 }
```

Posting message to `Worker` from component

```
this.worker.postMessage({cmd: 'CALCULATE', payload: payload});
```

This is working as expected. But I have couple of questions as

1. I have placed `worker.js` in `assets` folder so that it should get copied on `ng build`
2. `worker.js` is `JS` file not `TS`. I hope I can use `TS` instead
3. To use `TS` I can add `entry` in `webpack.config` and it will generate `bundle` for me. But I don't want to `eject webpack configuration` from `Angular CLI` project
4. I have checked [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-web-worker) package but with this I can only run the function is thread, I want code separation of all the function related for computation in `worker file`

So how can I use `Web worker` in `Angular CLI project` better way. I tried to search for the same but not found good article on this.

Reference: [Angular CLI generated app with Web Workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276044/angular-cli-generated-app-with-web-workers)

Comment: I'm looking for a way to implement it as well!

Comment: https://medium.com/@suresh.patidar/running-web-worker-in-angular-6-application-a-step-by-step-guide-74e88c566ba4