# How to Add Web Worker in Angular 7 application?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, web-worker

For achieving multithreading I am trying to implement web workers in angular 7. Following the official documentation when I run ng generate command It is not showing me the option
to create a web worker (this is because of the version of `angular/schematics` which is 7.2.0 and web worker command in angular 8 but I cannot update the version of my angular application because of other dependencies).

I have referred [this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/improve-performance-with-web-workers-497931fdef1b) blog to implement web workers in angular but it is showing me worker.js not error.

Can someone please suggest me the solution for this.

I have also tried this [Web worker setup in Angular 7.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53100379/web-worker-setup-in-angular-7-0-1) But At **step-1** it prompts warning that customWebPackConfig is not allowed here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web worker setup in Angular 7.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53100379/web-worker-setup-in-angular-7-0-1)

Comment: it does not work for my case. In step 1 it is giving me compile time error that property customwebPackconfig is not allowed here.

Comment: mention that in your question so that your question will not flagged duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @NickCoder for your recommendation to avoid duplication. Can you please suggest me some solution for this?