# How to import node module into web worker script?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, tensorflow.js

I am trying to build ionic app that uses tensorflowjs with coco-ssd model to detect objects on images from camera. Also, I need to be able to toggle flashlight while using camera.
When I use model's detection function just as `promise` call with `await`, it stops another 'threads' until detection is done. This is preventing flashlight to toggle instantly, and after button press (button that toggles flashlight), it has to wait for like half of a second to switch on or off.

I've decided to use coco-ssd in web worker, but I found out that I can't import node modules in web workers because of this error:

```
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module   worker-test.js:1
```

I've searched for some similar questions, but almost nobody imports modules in web workers, and the ones that do - they do it in javascript. To enable module importing in js you just have to pass another param to worker constructor: `new Worker('url/to/script.js', {type: 'module'})`
But the thing is, you can't pass second parameter to worker constructor in typescript, so I can't create a worker like that.

Relevant files:
**test.page.ts**

```
...
ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.testWorker();
  }

  testWorker() {
    const worker = new Worker('assets/worker-test/worker-test.js');

    worker.onmessage = function(event) {
      console.log('onmessage');
      console.log(event.data);
    };

    worker.postMessage('From main thread');
  }
...
```

**worker-test.js**

```
import * as cocoSsd from '@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd';

postMessage("posting message");

onmessage = function(data) {
    console.log('In worker');
    console.log(data.data);
    console.log(model);
};

let model;

cocoSsd.load().then((res) => {
    model = res;
});
```

ionic info:

```
   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0 (~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.6.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Can you please add your ts.config.json to the question ? I think you might need to change the compilation option of typescript to target either `es2015` or `esnext`

Comment: I have previously used the solution [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40130142/run-angular-2-app-in-web-worker-using-webpack) to run a web worker with Angular. The solution works fine in an Ionic setup too and definitely helps to improve performance.

Comment: I've just posted an answer to a similar question. It covers how to import a library inside a web worker generally, It covers parcel, webpack and mentions Angular CLI and projects managed with webpack - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931878/import-librarymoment-js-into-a-web-worker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compilation option of typescript should target either es2015 or esnext.

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["esnext", "webworker"],
  }
}
```

Additionnaly adding `"webworker"` will indicate that the project will use the webworker api.

Comment: That's wrong, because 'webworker' and 'dom' libs are mutually excluded, and I need 'dom' for sure

Comment: You can use "lib": ["esnext", "webworker"] for the webworker folder and "lib": ["esnext", "dom"] for the main folder. See how to structure one's project [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56356655/structuring-a-typescript-project-with-workers)